# Could we move directly from frequentist interpretation $P(data|hypothesis)$ to Bayes interpretation $P(hypothesis|data)$ by using Bayes theorem?

Tags: bayesian, mathematical-statistics, descriptive-statistics, frequentist

Could we move directly from frequentist interpretation $P(data|hypothesis)$ result to Bayes interpretation $P(hypothesis|data)$ result by using Bayes theorem, or is it not legitimate ?

Comment: Are you asking in terms of reversing the order of events in terms of calculating probabilities?

Comment: @ajax2112 : could we just translate from one interpretation to the other just by moving the terms in the Bayes theorem (Bayes formula)

Comment: If you are asking about rearranging the formula to calculate the opposite, yes you can do this. For a simple explanation watch this video from 0:10 to 1:15. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U_85TaXbeIo

Comment: @ajax2112 : thank you. I know technically how to do this simple algebra : the question is : is rearanging terms equivalent to transform from a frequentist to a bayesian *interpretation* ?

Comment: In a sense, however there is more at play here. This transformation is already based on a bayesian view of theoretical probabilities. If you collect data to determine P(data|hypothesis), then this transformation, whilst reversing our conditions, is still based on data collected using a frequentist methodology. So in a practical sense yes, however in the context of being able to label this as changing your overall approach, probably not.

Comment: all right thank you